# How to use the used by button in the GitHub repository?

Tags: github

Hello I have published a library in my GitHub repository and i want to use the **used by** button in the repository

I checked the repository settings but found no options to enable it
How do I enable this button in my repository?
[image]

Answer (score 14):

[netlify/staticgen issue 507](https://github.com/netlify/staticgen/issues/507#issuecomment-500597215) also asks, as you do:

> GitHub introduced a new metric, which I find much more relevant than stars or downloads. It shows the number of times a dependency is used by other repositories.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/103008/58381225-c4911d80-7fba-11e9-9179-1964cc18e963.png]

> How is this metric added to a repository?
>
> GitHub shows package metrics for projects that use a package manager, eg. if your repo has a `package.json`, it will use that to show your dependency network.

It is then automatically analyzed by GitHub, which scan other repository where your project reference shows up.

This was [announced last May 2019 by GitHub](https://twitter.com/github/status/1131468413983961088?lang=en).
And it can [be misleading (for monorepos)](https://twitter.com/angustweets/status/1134315377255522304)

Official documentation: "[Listing the projects that depend on a repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-projects-that-depend-on-a-repository)"

This is only for projects using:

- RubyGems
- NPM
- PyPI
- Maven (pom.xml only)
- Nuget

Check the [supported languages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on#supported-languages).

Comment: Is there anyway to disable it for a repo?

Comment: @arm Not that I know of. Maybe GitHub support can confirm that.

Comment: I saw it used by actions too but not as a button: https://github.com/actions/checkout